# Using pure HTML and CSS in modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I found this modal http://codepen.io/imprakash/pen/GgNMXO pure html and css no js. It's all great and all but how can I make it trigger without using a button or link? I want it to pop up to welcome visitors once the website load.

```
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
<div class="popup">
    <h2>Here i am</h2>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div class="content">
        Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this a bad practice

Comment: You could do that with javascript.

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to make it pop up on page load

Comment: guys, then just do not need js

Comment: Well I'm pretty bad at javascript.

Comment: see my answer. only css )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i modified your codepen

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: url(http://www.shukatsu-note.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/computer-564136_1280.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #06D85F;
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:not(:target) {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Popup/Modal Windows without JavaScript</h1>
<div class="box">
 <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>Here i am</h2>
  <a class="close" href="#popup1">&times;</a>
  <div class="content">
   Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what changes you did in short?

Comment: show modal if pseudoelement :target, i do show modal with :not(:target) and change close button that link reveive target id

Answer (score -1):

You could make it with animations. A quick example:

```css
#popup1 {
  animation-name: welcome;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
@keyframes welcome {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">Hey!</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As the technique uses `:target` psuedo class, you can directly target with appending the id of that pop up element.

Try this, http://codepen.io/imprakash/pen/GgNMXO#popup1

Just appended `#popup1` to target. Thus as soon as you open, popup will be targeted and opened.